# Where's my Applescript application?

Tags: applescript

In the Applications folder (El Capitan iMac) there is no Applescript editor. I've also checked the Utilities folder, but didn't find it. I don't think I would have mistakenly trashed it. Should I download a new one?

Answer (score 6):

The AppleScript editor is called *Script Editor.app* and usually resides in /Applications/Utilities/.

If the file was deleted you may get it back by reinstalling it separately with [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) by extracting it from "Install OS X El Capitan.app (10.11.0) > InstallESD" and updating it with [OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1876?locale=en_US) or immediately from "Install OS X El Capitan.app (10.11.5) > InstallESD".

Comment: Script Editor.app is protected by System Integrity Protection, so removal is conditional on that having been disabled.

Answer (score -1):

As klanomath stated, it's called script editor, and resides in /applications/utilities

If it's not there, simply restarting into recovery and doing a reinstall of the OS should put it back

Here are the steps, if you're not certain on how to reinstall OS X:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904